# How to cast the following string to a date or timestamp?

Tags: date, amazon-athena, presto

I have strings in a table like this:

2020-11-16 03:46:26.007+00

I am trying to convert these to date so that I can extract the day (2020-11-16) from it.

```
SELECT date_parse(updatedat,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s.%f+%x') FROM table LIMIT 10
```

Unfortunately it returns: 0000-11-16 03:27:13.017

What is the right way to convert this string to a date or timestamp that I can extract the part I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That string follows the the canonical format for timestamps, so you should be able to just cast it to a `timestamp` type and then to a `date`:

```
> select cast(cast('2020-11-16 03:46:26.007+00' as timestamp) as date);
   _col0
------------
 2020-11-16
(1 row)
```